Add some line height between two lines of a markdown table in a markdown document producing a pdf with pandoc
Inside a markdown document, I have to replace an image by a table with some Latex formulas inside.
I'm doing fine, but I'd enjoy founding again most of the colors and the spacing my image had.
Yet, my markdown is this one (I keep for some time the image that will disappear later):
![Principaux cosinus, sinus, tangentes](mathematiques/principaux_cosinus_sinus_tangentes.jpg){width=60%}

| $x$       | $0$ | $30^\circ$ ou $\frac{\pi}{6}$ | $45^\circ$ ou $\frac{\pi}{4}$ | $60^\circ$ ou $\frac{\pi}{3}$ | $90^\circ$ ou $\frac{\pi}{2}$ |
|-----------|-----|-------------------------------|-------------------------------|-------------------------------|-------------------------------|
| $\sin(x)$ | 0   | $\frac{1}{2}$                 | $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$          | $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$          | 1                             |   
| $\cos(x)$ | 1   | $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$          | $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$          | $\frac{1}{2}$                 | 1                             |   
| $\tan(x)$ | 0   | $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$          | $1$                           | $\sqrt{3}$                    | Non définie                   |   

and it produces this:

To start my customization, I'd like to increase the line height between:

the sin(x) and the cos(x) lines
and the cos(x) and the tan(x) lines.

I need the statements or directives added to my markdown document to be compatible with the pdf generation I'm producing with pandoc.
For information, the pandoc command I'm using is:
pandoc -f markdown-implicit_figures --syntax-definition=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/java.xml --syntax-definition=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/java.xml --metadata-file=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/metadata.json --include-in-header=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/apprentissage-header-include.tex --include-in-header=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/apprentissage-include.tex --bibliography=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/bibliographie.bib --citeproc "${source}".md -o "${source}".pdf


You can either add a newline (backslash followed by newline) to every row, or change the pandoc LaTeX template: see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates
